# how to send two parmenter in html anchor to asp.net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to send id and a string in a anchor

```
     <a id="senurl" href="/Admin/Coupon1/Reject/@Model.id" class="btn">Reject Coupon</a>
```

or do this 
Reject Coupon

```
**action**

    public ActionResult Reject(int id, string ChangeId){

    }
```

or do this 
Reject Coupon

Answer (score 2):

Use `Html.ActionLink` instead of manually creating the URL. It's cleaner, handles relative paths, and considers the registered routes.

Example:

```
@Html.ActionLink( 
     "Reject Coupon",
     "Reject", 
     new { id = Model.id, ChangeId = "foo" } )
```

If you want more control, you can generate the URL separate from the anchor with `Url.Action`

Answer (score 1):

and you can use this

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Reject", "controllername", 
    new { id = Model.id, ChangeId = "foo" })'>
Hello</a>
```

if you want use html